# Disabling md-waves on a disabled button

Tags: aurelia, materialize

Consider a materialize button like this:

```
<button md-button="disabled.bind: !dirty" md-waves class="primary">Save</button>
```

The button can be disabled by controlling the `dirty` bit but even in disabled mode, its waves are active and working. How can I can disable the waves on a disabled button?

I've read the `md-waves` [source code](https://github.com/aurelia-ui-toolkits/aurelia-materialize-bridge/blob/master/src/waves/waves.js) and it seems there's no `disabled` bindable property designed for it. Is there any way except adding the `disabled` property?

Comment: <md-button disabled.bind="dirty"> is it work?

Comment: @JayDi No, that does not even disable the button.

Comment: @Mehran The md-button attribute is attached to a native html button. That's the reason why `disabled` wil affect that button. That means that the button should receive no click events.
I've tried to reproduce this with a gist but the waves are correctly disabled there: https://gist.run/?id=7e89716d8bc54e9b389539ddaecbc909